# ssDNA library amplification

Tags: dna, pcr

Assume we are given approx. 80,000 dsDNA fragments of 40 bps length each.
I would like to amplify of each of the 80,000 fragments just one particular strand, such that I obtain amplified 80,000 ssDNA fragments of just 40 bps.

Also beforehand if could be helpful to amplify the 80,000 dsDNA fragments, so where the amplified fragments stay double-stranded.

If you could help me for both amplification steps, particularly the first one, I would be very delighted!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not possible (without any additional upstream steps). For example, how would you define which of the strand should be amplified?

Comment: Well I think of extending the fragment by say 10 bps upstream and downstream for each fragment, which is identical for all. Then I could selectively amplify a particular strand via the primers that match to the 10 bps each.

Comment: How would you add this 10bp sequence; by ligation?